# TemplateDoesNotExist error in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I searched a lot of similar questions on StackOverflow but couldn't find an answer to this problem. I was following the guide at [tango with django](http://tangowithdjango.com).
My file directory looks like this :-

```
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- manage.py
|-- media
|   `-- rango.jpg
|-- rango
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- admin.pyc
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- migrations
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- views.py
|   `-- views.pyc
|-- rango.db
|-- static
|   |-- rango1.jpg
|   `-- rango.jpg
|-- tango_with_django_project
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- settings.pyc
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- wsgi.py
|   `-- wsgi.pyc
`-- templates
    `-- rango
        |-- about.html
        |-- index.html
        `-- order.html
```

On starting the server, I get a TemplateDoesNotExist error which looks like this :-

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine :
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/kalpesh/tango_with_django_project/templates/templates/rango/about.html (Source does not exist)
```

What's strange to me is the `templates/templates` that appears in the path name. Here is my `settings.py` file :-

```
#New stuff
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)
DATABASE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'rango.db')

#Template new stuff
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates")
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS' : [TEMPLATE_PATH],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**What's going wrong? If I make identical HTML files inside** `./templates/templates/rango`, the app works.

Comment: Add `print(PROJECT_PATH); exit()` somewhere and look what logs in the console.

Comment: `/home/kalpesh/tango_with_django_project/tango_with_django_project`

Comment: I edited the comment.

Comment: Here you go `/home/kalpesh/tango_with_django_project`

Comment: Post the code you have in your template, the problem is there.

Comment: Yes you are right! I had this line in `index.html` :- `templates/rango/about.html`

Comment: What's the right thing to do here?

Comment: The right thing is not to include the "templates/" prefix there.

Comment: The thing that worries me here is that the wrong code was inside `<!--`, like `<!--<div class="basic">
   {% include "rango/about.html" %}
  </div> -->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django allows you to reference the templates relatively to the root of the directories listed in `DIRS` (in this case only `templates`); so you only need to pass `rango/about.html`.